# Converting octave / matlab equation from 2D to 3D plot

Tags: matlab, octave

Converting 2D code / plot into 3D code / plot.

I can create a 2D plot using the code below which produces the plot below.  But how can I turn this 2D plot into a 3D plot.  I tried using meshgrid to do this but the plot it creates is not in 3D and the curves no longer show up in the plot.  I included the 2D code that I'm using below along with the plot it produces.  Also at the bottom I show the 3D code and the Incorrect plot it produces at the end.

[image: Formula image]

```
%---2D working code    
clear all,clf reset,tic,clc, close all, 
    S=[15.3039,10.3612,7.9153,6.3793,5.3019,4.4955,3.8656,3.3584,2.9405,2.5903,2.2926,2.0367,1.8146,1.6204,1.4496,1.2983,1.1638,1.04377,.93622,.83959,.75256,.67401,.603,.53871,.48045,.42762,.37969,.33619,.29673,.26094,.22852,.19917,.17265,.14874,.12722,.10791,.090664,.075316,.061733,.049793,.039383,.030399,.0227475,.0163414,.0111008,.0069525,.0038286,.0016664,.0004081];
    x = linspace(0,1,100);
    T = 1.12;
    for bb = 1:length(S)
      y1=exp(log(1-x.^(S(1,bb)*T))/(S(1,bb)*T)); %right to left top to bottom
      hold on
      plot(x,y1,'r')
    end
```

[image: 2D correct plot of equation]

Code I tried using mesh grid with but it's not in 3D and the curve pattern no longer exists.

```
%---3D non-working code
clear all,clf reset,tic,clc, close all, 
    S=[15.3039,10.3612,7.9153,6.3793,5.3019,4.4955,3.8656,3.3584,2.9405,2.5903,2.2926,2.0367,1.8146,1.6204,1.4496,1.2983,1.1638,1.04377,.93622,.83959,.75256,.67401,.603,.53871,.48045,.42762,.37969,.33619,.29673,.26094,.22852,.19917,.17265,.14874,.12722,.10791,.090664,.075316,.061733,.049793,.039383,.030399,.0227475,.0163414,.0111008,.0069525,.0038286,.0016664,.0004081];
    x = linspace(0,1,10);
    T = 1.12;
    [SS,xx]=meshgrid(S,x); %create meshgrid data

    for bb = 1:length(S)
      z=exp(log(1-xx.^(SS*T))/(SS*T)); %right to left top to bottom
      hold on
      plot(xx,SS,z,'r')
    end
```

Incorrect 3D image code produces
[image]

PS: I'm using Octave 4.2.2 which is similar to matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using something like `surf`:

```
y1 = zeros(length(x),length(S));
for ii = 1:length(x)
   for jj = 1:length(S)
      y1(ii,jj) = exp(log(1-x(ii)^(S(jj)*T))/(S(jj)*T));
   end
end
surf(S,x,y1,'faceColor','interp','linestyle','none')
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: This is asking for some `'faceColor','interp','linestyle','none'` :D